# accessing a variable from dynamically loaded external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an external js file being loaded (which I cannot modify) with document.createElement() and I need to access a variable from it. The problem is, I don't know when does it finish loading. I tried jQuery's document ready function but it seems to deploy sooner than the javascript file. I am able to access the variable like this though:

```
setTimeout("console.log(swifttagdiv.firstChild.firstChild.src)", 5000);
```

but this is just a test to see if the variable is global. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject the script by using Javascript instead of putting it in your page. This way you can control when it is loaded.

Here's a function I use to inject code in pages dynamically:

```
    function inject(src, cb, target){
        target = target || document.body;
        var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
        s.charset = 'UTF-8';
        if(typeof cb === 'function'){ 
            s.onload = function(){
                cb(s);
            }; 
            s.onreadystatechange = function () {
                (/loaded|complete/).test(s.readyState) && cb(s);
            };                     
        }
        s.src = src;
        target.appendChild(s);
        return s;
    }
```

to use it:

```
inject('/path/to/file.js', function(script){
   //your code here
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var checkvarint = setInterval(function(){
  if(swifttagdiv.firstChild.firstChild.src){
    varLoaded(); clearInterval(checkvarint);
  }
},10);

function varLoaded(){
    alert("LOADED!");
    alert(swifttagdiv.firstChild.firstChild.src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897414/accessing-a-variable-from-dynamically-loaded-external-javascript-file/5897516#5897516) is great.
Here is the same thing only less abstracted, perhaps it will be instructive

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement( 'script' );
scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
scriptElement.src  = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core-debug.js";

function loadHandler() {
    alert( 'loaded' );
}

// for ie
scriptElement.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if( this.readyState == 'complete' ){
        loadHandler();
    }
}
// for others
scriptElement.onload= loadHandler;

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( scriptElement );
```